# SoapUI - JDBC remove table name from the response

Tags: mysql, jdbc, soapui

I was using ORACLE JDBC driver all my query and assertions are based on column names. Now I need to use MySQL database instead.

When I will make request, I can see in result are table name and dot in response.

How to remove them?

If event handler, then we need to use `SubmitListener.afterSubmit` - but I have no idea, how to obtain response, modify it, and return.

JDBC driver config parameter sounds like is not available. I tried the Postgres driver, but not works in MySQL server.

I am trying to remove the parts marked in yellow:

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with some sample code as per [these](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instructios.

Comment: Do you get the same when you run the queries in a DB client ? It looks like a table addressing setting on your production DB. I would guess it is the DB, not SoapUI.

Comment: Try use [schema name] before your select.

Comment: Hello, nice idea.. 
Unfortunetally.. I can see in WireShark is submitting the talbe names in the response.. 
Hm.. 
So the issue is not related to SoapUI, but to MySQL server.

Any idea? What to search ? Because I did not found anything on MySQL documentaton.. maybe wrongly searching.. 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try what I said in my previous comment: `use [your db/schema name]; select ...`